# How to use --connectionStringConfigPath for FluentMigrator MSBuild runner

Tags: msbuild, fluent-migrator

How do you use the --connectionStringConfigPath for FluentMigrator when using the MSBuild runner?

The documentation says

> Connection (required)
>
> The connection string to the server and database you want to execute
>   your migrations against. This can be a full connection string or the
>   name of the connection string stored in a config file.
>
> When specifying a named connection string, FluentMigrator searchs for
>   it in this order:
>
> 1. The specified config file via --connectionStringConfigPath parameter
> 2. Target assembly’s config file
> 3. Machine.config config file

I was not able to get this to work and couldn't find any examples of usage with FluentMigrator's MSBuild runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connectionStringConfigPath parameter is used in conjuction with the Connection parameter. The Connection parameter specifies the name of the connection string.

This is an example of the migrate task:

```
<Migrate Database="sqlserver2012"
    Connection="SRVConnectionString"
    ConnectionStringConfigPath="db.config"
    Target="./Migrations/bin/Debug/Migrations.dll">
</Migrate>
```

And this is the db.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <clear />
        <add name="SRVConnectionString" connectionString="server=SQLEXPRESS;uid=test;pwd=test;database=Test"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I will update the [wiki](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/MSBuild-Runner-Options) with this example.